# Is possible upgrade RAM for a MBP 13.3/2.9/2X4GB/750/SD?

Tags: hardware, upgrade, memory, hardware-recommendation

I have an old MacBook Pro - it is:

- MBP 13.3/2.9/2X4GB/750/SD
- Model No: A1278

I want to know if is possible upgrade to 16 or even with 32 GB of RAM - if yes, what are the correct specs of each memory? It to buy the correct pair.

Comment: That MacBook Pro identifier spans models from 2008 through 2012.  The linked dupe will answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get this as its official designation -
'Apple MacBook Pro "Core i7" 2.9 13" Mid-2012' - using EveryMac https://everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook_pro/specs/macbook-pro-core-i7-2.9-13-mid-2012-unibody-usb3-specs.html
This is [approximately] what it should say if you look at 'About this Mac' under the  menu.
The 'A1278' type numbers are not a reliable start point. Sometimes they can cover 5 years of not even similar models.

The RAM in this Mac *is* upgradeable - though you'll have to bin the existing 8GB to do it, it has only two slots. Maximum is 16GB [2 x 8GB].

The best way to find it is to search by that model description. Everymac itself has sponsored links to find the correct RAM, or major online sellers have 'configurator' structures to find the right memory.

Use a reliable source to see how to disassemble, such as [iFixit](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/MacBook+Pro+13-Inch+Unibody+Mid+2012+RAM+Replacement/10374) - this one is relatively simple, but you need to be sure to disconnect the battery before changing the RAM. SMC reset is always a good procedure after a hardware change, too.

*Just to note* Watch out for the 2012 as there are two revisions, quite different. 'mid-2012' and 'retina 2012'. They are vastly different machines.

Comment: For the audience, the upgrade was possible successfully, now the mentioned MacBook Pro has 16GB