# Is possible insert safety the Hynix HMT351S6CFR8C-PB sticks into the Apple MacBook Pro "Core i5" 2.3 13" Early 2011?

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, upgrade, memory

For [Apple MacBook Pro "Core i5" 2.3 13" Early 2011 Specs](https://everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook_pro/specs/macbook-pro-core-i5-2.3-13-early-2011-unibody-thunderbolt-specs.html), about the RAM is indicated

```
Supports 1333 MHz PC3-10600 DDR3 SDRAM.
```

And for [Apple MacBook Pro "Core i7" 2.9 13" Mid-2012 Specs](https://everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook_pro/specs/macbook-pro-core-i7-2.9-13-mid-2012-unibody-usb3-specs.html), about the RAM is indicated

```
Supports 1600 MHz PC3-12800 DDR3L SDRAM SO-DIMMs (204-pin).
```

For the latter was possible do an upgrade from 8GB to 16GB. Therefore it confirms the following post:

- [Is possible upgrade RAM for a MBP 13.3/2.9/2X4GB/750/SD? [duplicate]](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/458313/is-possible-upgrade-ram-for-a-mbp-13-3-2-9-2x4gb-750-sd)

Now the former laptop belongs to my uncle and it has currently 4GB and he wants do the respective upgrade. Therefore I want give to him my two removed sticks. 8GB is enough for him.

The sticks have the following data in their stickers:

```
Hynix
4GB 2Rx8 PC3 - 12800S -11-11-F3
HMT351S6CFR8C-PB N0 AA 1235
```

Using google the `HMT351S6CFR8C-PB` search term exists the following:

- [Hynix 4GB PC3-12800 DDR3 1600MHz Non-ECC Unbuffered HMT351S6CFR8C-PB](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00A8J2OUM)

The Figure shown is almost the same as my current sticks.
The mime has `HMT351S6CFR8C-PB N0 AA 1235` and in the Figure has `HMT351S6CFR8C-PB N0 AA 1228`. Therefore observe `1235` vs `1228`

**Question**

- Is possible insert safety the `Hynix` sticks into the `Apple MacBook Pro "Core i5" 2.3 13" Early 2011`?

But taking the following observations:

1. The speeds are different. The former requests `1333MHZ` and the sticks have `1600MHZ`. I am assuming a downgrade should happen in peace. Pls confirm if it is correct or not.
2. The former requests `DDR3` and the latter `DDR3L`. I know that `DDR3` can accept `DRR3L`. Just in case I need your reconfirmation.

**Extra Question**

The 2nd point is confuse because the removed sticks have in their stickers `PC3` and not `PC3L`. Furthermore the Amazon's link indicates that the stick is `DDR3` too. Therefore for the latter MacBook Pro: how was possible from the beginning that `DDR3` worked in a slot requesting `DDR3L`? According with my understanding it is not possible.